# Multiple file upload popup is shown in file upload using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload for uploading files. But am getting 5 popups for uploading files. How to resolve this. Below am giving am codes please check,

**Html Code**

```
<div class="" id="clickToUpload" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload new file</div>
<input type="file" style="display:none" ng-model="picFile" name="file" class="uploadFile" onchange= "angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" />
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.uploadOpgsFile = function(){
    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".uploadFile")).click();
};
$scope.fileNameChanged = function(element){
    console.log(element.files);
}
```

Comment: Could you create a snippet or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Am trying to create a snippet or jsfiddle also but it is not working.

Comment: Could you provide a collaboration link to the fiddle?I can try and help out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yhks3jy0/

Comment: It is fixed as this html code is coming under ng-repeat, so querySelectorAll will take all the ".uploadFile" elements  shows the popup multiple times.